# Sequelize not letting me insert new rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, backend

I have this function in a server in my backend server:

```
async create(data) {
    try {
      console.log("User ", data);
      const newUser = await models.User.create({
        ...data,
        password: await bcrypt.hash(`${data.password}`, 10),
      });
      delete newUser.dataValues.password;
      return newUser;

    } catch(error) {
      console.error("Error creating user:", error);
      throw new Error('Signup failed'); // or handle the error accordingly
    }
  }
```

This is what I get when I console.log the data:

```
{ 
username: 'test', email: 'sometest@gmail.com', password: 'Hello1234#'
}
```

but when its executed I get this error:

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO "user" ("id") VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING "id";
>
> name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
> parent: error: null value in column "username" of relation "user" violates not-null constraint
> {
> length: 236,
> severity: 'ERROR',
> code: '23502',
> detail: 'La fila que falla contiene (6, null, null, null).',
> hint: undefined,
> position: undefined,
> internalPosition: undefined,
> internalQuery: undefined,
> where: undefined,
> schema: 'public',
> table: 'user',
> column: 'username',
> dataType: undefined,
> constraint: undefined,
> file: 'execmain.c',
> line: '1974',
> routine: 'ExecConstraints',
> sql: 'INSERT INTO "user" ("id") VALUES (DEFAULT) RETURNING "id";',
> parameters: []
> }

I don't really understand why I'm getting this.

This is the model for the User:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const USER_TABLE = "user";
const UserTableSchema = {id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER,primaryKey: true,autoIncrement: true,allowNull: false},username: {type: DataTypes.STRING,allowNull: false,},email: {type: DataTypes.STRING,allowNull: false,},password: {type: DataTypes.STRING,allowNull: false,},};
class User extends Model {// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-varsstatic associate(_models) {// No associations to define}
static config(sequelize) {return {sequelize,tableName: USER_TABLE,modelName: "User",timestamps: false,};}}
module.exports = { USER_TABLE, UserTableSchema, User };
```

Even when I retrieve some rows using find all, I only get the id, not the username, email or password, so I don't know if I should change the way I configured sequelize.

This is the sequelize.js file:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const { config } = require('../../../config/config');
const setupModels = require('./models');

// Build the database connection URI
const USER = encodeURIComponent(config.dbUser);
const PASSWORD = encodeURIComponent(config.dbPassword);
const URI = `postgres://${USER}:${PASSWORD}@${config.dbHost}:${config.dbPort}/${config.dbName}`;

// Set the options for Sequelize
const options = {
  dialect: config.dialect,
  host: config.dbHost,
  define: {
    timestamps: false,
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: false,
  },
  logging: console.log,
};

// Create a new Sequelize instance with the connection URI and options
const sequelize = new Sequelize(URI, options);

// Setup the models using the created Sequelize instance
setupModels(sequelize);

module.exports = sequelize;
```

These are the dependencies I'm using:

```
"@hapi/boom": "^10.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.3",
    "html-pdf": "^3.0.1",
    "i18n": "^0.15.0",
    "ionicons": "^6.0.3",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "joi-to-swagger": "^6.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "puppeteer": "^19.2.2",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.7.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.21.4",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.5.1",
    "sharp": "^0.30.7",
    "swagger-autogen": "^2.21.5",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.5.0"
```

Comment: The column `username` is not allowed to have the value `NULL`, and you are not inserting it.

Comment: I am inserting it, this is what i get in the console log:

{
  username: 'test',
  email: 'sometest@gmail.com',
  password: 'Hello1234#'
}

Comment: The info about your console log is information that should have been available in the question, Please use [edit] to add it to the question.

Comment: Can you check (using a [PostgreSQL Client](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients), if your table is created according to your expectations?

Comment: Yeah, i already checked the properties of the table created in postgres, and it matches what i configured in the model file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your `setupModels` function work? From the log it seems like it haven't passed any of data properties to the `create` method.

Comment: This is my index.js file inside the models folder:

const { User, UserSchema } = require('./user.model');

function setupModels (sequelize) {
  User.init(UserSchema, User.config(sequelize));

  User.associate(sequelize.models);
}

module.exports = setupModels;

Comment: I also see that you are exporting `UserTableSchema`, but when doing require you are deconstructing to `UserSchema`. After reproducing your code and making these imports and exports consistent in naming it worked out.